# javascript string to statements

Tags: javascript, string, eval

When we concatenate a string to an object, it automatically converts all the values into string.

Is there a way where it is not converted to a string or the string can be converted back to a statement.

I'm trying to do something like if I type length, it adds together to the string variable and counts the length of the string.

```
var property = prompt("Add the Property");
var myObject = "This is the String";
var propertyCombinedWithObject = myObject + "." + property;
console.log(propertyCombinedWithObject);
```

The result is a string "This is the String".length rather than counting the numbers of the string.

I have tried

```
eval(propertyCombinedWithObject)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: prototype function will do the same as you asking

Comment: @bergi, thanks for pointing out that it is a duplicate question. I think it's a different question. Though we may have the same answer, but I wouldn't understand that question relating to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a property of an object, you can use the square bracket notation:

```
var property = prompt("Add the Property");
var myObject = "This is the String";
var propertyCombinedWithObject = myObject[property];
console.log(propertyCombinedWithObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you are looking for is JS-objects with bracket notation.

```
var property = prompt("Add the Property");
var myObject = "This is the String";
console.log(myObject[property]);
```